# Find tuples with same starting and ending alphabets

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tuples

Complete the given method called solve which takes as parameter a list of tuples called A.

Each tuple contains some strings. You have to print the indexes of those tuples whose first element's first alphabet is the same as the last element's last alphabet.

Example, for this list: [('hello','hi'), ('his', 'name', 'archith'), ('kremlin', 'russia', 'spartak'), ('error', 'none', 'wave'), ('indeed', 'numbers', 'work')]
The output is:
1 2 3

```
    def solve(A):
# write your code from here
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i):
        if A[j][i].startswith('h')==A[j+1][i+1].endswith('h'):
            print(A[i])
```

but im getting error!

Comment: *What* error are you getting, and what have you done to try and fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'first alphabet' / 'last alphabet' ?  An [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet) is a set of symbols used in a given language (e.g. greek, mandarin, japanese).   Do you mean word, string or character ?

Comment: In your example, all the words are from the same alphabet. I don't understand your homework

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
lst = [('hello','hi'), ('his', 'name', 'archith'), ('kremlin', 'russia', 'spartak'), ('error', 'none', 'wave'), ('indeed', 'numbers', 'work')] 


for e,i in enumerate(lst):
    if i[0][0] == i[-1][-1]:
        print(e,"=>",i)
```